# How long do tar-like blankets on a roof typically last? If installing a solar farm on five year old roof, should additional blankets be added?

Tags: roof

On a single story flat roof private home I am installing a solar farm. On the roof there is now a tar-like blanket. There are no signs of damage that I can see, but I suspect that it will be a major undertaking to resurface that after the solar farm is in place.

**Should I consider laying an additional tar-like blanket before installing the solar farm on the roof, if the blanket is five years old but shows no sign or wear or damage?**

I cannot find what these blankets are called in English. This is an example. It's not my roof, just a photo that I found online, that shows the blankets in question:

[image]

Comment: If the tar-like blanket is a standard product sold in stores then you should read the label to figure out its longevity.

Comment: The material is sold in bulk, non-labelled. I can not get a straight answer from asking either in stores or from people who install it.

Comment: Are you sure it's OK to install solar panels over such a roofing surface?  We looked into installing solar on the roof of our church, but they said that was a no-go because the flat roof was covered with a rubber membrane.

Comment: So ask for the manufacturer's name or figure out the vendor that sold it to them and contact the manufacturer. One manufacturer might be 10 years and the next guy says 40 years. It's really impossible to answer your question as it stands. Consider adding a picture, maybe someone here can identify the product.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thank you, I've added a picture.

Comment: Does the top surface have rocky granules?

Comment: Looks like Modified Bitumen roofing to me. Check out https://flatroofdoc.com/roofing-materials/

Comment: Regardless, you need to reach out to the specific manufacturer and ask about solar panel compatibility.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thank you! Now that I know how it is called in English - Modified Bitumen - I can find far more information. I have no way of finding the manufacturer, the contractor won't remember that so many years later. But now I can at least learn more. Thank  you.

Comment: Nice, it sounds like you have 2 main questions to answer: can you install solar panels without the roof leaking and which will last longer, the roof or the solar panels? Solar panel longevity is about 25-30 years and if you have 2-ply modified bitumen roofing then it's good for 40 years or more according to that link I shared.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus It does seem that 40 years is a best case scenario for a well-maintained roof, and in fact I do maintain it. Please post your comment as an answer so that I could accept it. Thank you!

Comment: I see a roof being put on top of an old roof. That's generally not a good indicator for roof longevity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like Modified Bitumen (MB) roofing to me. Check out https://flatroofdoc.com/roofing-materials/

Solar panel longevity is about 25-30 years and if you have 2-ply modified bitumen roofing then it's good for 40 years or more according to that link I shared.

I guess the main question at hand is whether or not you can install solar panels without incurring roof leaks. I believe common practice is to dab some tar where you plan to drive screws into your roof. Based on the article it would seem wise to embed granules into the surface of the tar to protect it from UV light.